# ¿Cómo seleccionar texto dentro de corchetes?

Tags: r, rstudio

Quisiera saber como indicarle a RStudio que me seleccione todo lo contenido entre [].

Si es con el paquete stringr mejor. 
Gracias

Este es el dataframe vector de strings que tengo.

```
View(chat)
                                                                       chat
1         [4/11/16 21:30:46] Pedro Camacho: Y tiene que ser la sunix HAHAHA
2                                        [4/11/16 21:52:29] Fidel Morla: Si
3 [5/11/16 01:09:12] Manuel Pagan: Curry's 3-point streak ends at 157 games
4                            [5/11/16 06:44:45] Pedro Camacho: Me avisa Fid
5                                       [5/11/16 06:45:03] Fidel Morla: Sal
6                                      [5/11/16 06:45:16] Pedro Camacho: Ok
```

Comment: Bienvenido @Fidel E. Morla M. a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Usando `str_match()` y expresiones regulares

```
library(stringr)
v <- c("[4/11/16 21:30:46] Pedro Camacho: Y tiene que ser la sunix HAHAHA",
       "[4/11/16 21:52:29] Fidel Morla: Si",
       "[5/11/16 01:09:12] Manuel Pagan: Curry's 3-point streak ends at 157 games",
       "[5/11/16 06:44:45] Pedro Camacho: Me avisa Fid",
       "[5/11/16 06:45:03] Fidel Morla: Sal",
       "[5/11/16 06:45:16] Pedro Camacho: Ok",
       "[5/11/16 06:51:06] Marcos Noyola: Levanten a Martinez",
       "[5/11/16 06:51:34] Marcos Noyola: Por favor")


str_match(v, "\\[(.+)\\]")[,2]

[1] "4/11/16 21:30:46" "4/11/16 21:52:29" "5/11/16 01:09:12" "5/11/16 06:44:45" "5/11/16 06:45:03" "5/11/16 06:45:16"
[7] "5/11/16 06:51:06" "5/11/16 06:51:34"
```